# CORBA + IDL + Java: need help with writing servant

Tags: java, design-patterns, corba, idl

I have a defined idl file, which looks like this:

```
module Banking {
    typedef string Transactions[5];
    typedef long AccountId;

    interface Account {
        exception InsufficientFunds {};

        readonly attribute double balance;
        long lodge(in double amount);
        long withdraw(in double amount) raises (InsufficientFunds);
        readonly attribute Transactions transactions;   
    };

    interface Bank {
        long accountCount();
        double totalMoney();
        Account account(in AccountId accNr);
    };
};
```

which I compile with idlj. I have defined a BankServant, used by the client to communicate with the server and I have a working program with almost all methods implemented. My only problem is that I don't know how can I implement `account(in AccountId accNr)` method, which in turn will return the proper Account object. As I don't know CORBA and I am just helping a friend, I would like to ask for some kind of solutions / examples / tutorialis which may help me to hack a simple yet working class layout for dealing with that kind of situations.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the policies you're using for the POA (the Portable Object Adapter). Assuming you're using the RootPOA in the server, you have to:

1. Create an implementation object for the Account object. This is usually called `AccountImpl` or `AccountServant` as I see in the name of the bank servant.

   `AccountServant as = new AccountServant(accNr);`
2. You have to register the object in the POA. This, again, has to do with the policies you've selected for your POA. using the default Root POA:

   `org.omg.CORBA.Object o = rootPOA.servant_to_reference( as );`
3. Narrow it to the correct `Account` type using the IDL compiler generated `AccountHelper`:

   `Account acc = AccountHelper.narrow(o);`
4. Return it

   `return acc;`

This code assumes you've written a constructor for the `AccountServant` java object that accepts the account number as its first argument. You have to provide the `BankServant` also with a reference to the POA in which you want to register the newly created `Account` objects.

There are lots of tutorials. See [this one](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/javaidl/javaidl.html) for example, as the set of options for the POA are so many that require a book to explain them all :).

Comment: Thank you very much - I did not want to learn all about the CORBA as this ought to be a 15 minute help task, yet I had few problems, even after reading some tutorials.